# Изменить название ссылки перед ее отображением на странице JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, wordpress

На сайте есть ссылка

```
<li class="active">
  <a href="#commentlist-container" >Комментарии</a>
</li>
```

Изменяю ее название вот таким образом

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".active [href^=\'#commentlist-container\']:first").text("Благодарности");
});
```

Все работает, но проблема в том, что после обновления сначала появляется "Комментарии", а затем сменяется на "Благодарности". Скажите пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы название "Благодарности" выводилось сразу же?

Comment: Заменить `Комментарии` на `Благодарности` в html что мешает? Можно вставить js код прямо под этим блоком без `document.ready`, тогда будет сразу.

Comment: Заменить Комментарии на Благодарности в html что мешает? - необходимо именно из jquery. Попробовал без docready, так вообще не работает

Comment: значит у вас jquery в подвале подключен

Comment: это исключено) во-первых, работаю с wordpress через функцию, которая подключает скрипты в head. во-вторых проверял)

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev в этом вся и суть. WP - в нем хрен что найдешь. от того и приходится делать такие костыли. Сам не раз сталкивался.

Comment: @YuriGo как вариант поставить её `opacity: 0`. и когда изменяешь текст делать `.fadeTo(200, 1)`.

Comment: так в том то и суть, что если поставить opacity по умолчанию 0, только в тех местах где нужна надпись "Комментарии", будет пусто.

Comment: а css вариант не подойдет?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cwh2LLjz/

Comment: хм...а можете поподробнее объяснить?)) вот смотрите, в коде я сначала получаю текущий id страницы, допустим, он равен 84, после чего смотрю if(id == 84) то выводим "Благодарности". Немного не понятно как css может помочь..